# Keycloak Patterns Constraints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I have a problem with Keycloak constraint in my spring boot app, I need to restrict access to endpoints by role.

In the previous version of my app I only used spring security with the following config:

```
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/brands/models/{id}").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/brands/models/{id}").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)

            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/brands/models/versions").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/brands/models/versions/{id}").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/brands/models/versions/{id}/default").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE) 
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/brands/models/versions/{id}").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)

            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/brands/models/versions/{id}/price").hasAnyAuthority(USER_ROLE)
```

In my new app with Keycloak(without Spring Security) I need to do the same in the application.yml.

for example like

```
security-constraints[0]:
    auth-roles:
      - admin
    security-collections[0]:
      name: endpoints models
      patterns:
        - /brands/models
        - /brands/models/{id}
      methods:
        - POST
        - PUT
        - DELETE
    security-collections[1]:
      name: endpoints versions
      patterns:
        - /brands/models/versions
        - /brands/models/versions/{id}
        - /brands/models/versions/{id}/default
      methods:
        - POST
        - PUT
        - DELETE
security-constraints[1]:
    auth-roles:
      - user
    security-collections[0]:
      name: endpoints modelos
      patterns:
        - /brands/models/versions/{id}/price
      methods:
        - PUT
```

The idea is that the **admin role** can do CRUD operations to these endpoints

/brands/models
/brands/models/versions

And the **user role** only can update attributes in the endpoint

/brands/models/versions/{id}/price

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: It does not look bad to me even if the configuration should be more like this ( https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter ):

```yml
keycloak:
  security-constraints:
     - auth-roles: ...
       secuirty-collections:
          - ...
     - auth-roles:
       ...
```

What is your problem?

Comment: when I used  path variable {id} in the url, the API response even without token, as if I didn't have security

Comment: If I use * instead of path variable {id} works correctly for the *admin role*, but don't works for the *user role*

Comment: I did not see `{id}` in your patterns. You need to use servlet url-pattern here, so something like `{id}` will not work.